# How can i read hyperlink data from excel using angular?

Tags: angular, excel, hyperlink, xlsx, worksheet

I trying to excel file data read using angular. I used below code for Data Read.

```
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true, dateNF: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
      ////console.log("this.data : " , this.data);
    };
```

Using this code I successfully read normal data.

**Does anyone knows how to read hyperlink data from an excel file.**

[image]

Comment: what the console.log(this.data) shows?

Comment: It's shows "IMG"